# How to sum the differences between each pair, then sum each pair's results using nedb

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, foreach, nedb

I have a nedb database `trades.json` where I am writing imaginary stock trades:

```
{"buySell":"BUY","currentPrice":431.55,"_id":"GyTaUKVOCa9x5APS"},
{"buySell":"SELL","currentPrice":431.77,"_id":"Re9VhGrW9ZoiOKFe"},
{"buySell":"BUY","currentPrice":431.65,"_id":"TJrn63bIV8sKBFYh"},
{"buySell":"SELL","currentPrice":431.7539,"_id":"qrsz2l3UVKpQEks8"}
```

I am trying to find the difference of `currentPrice` between each `buySell` pair of "BUY" and "SELL" then add those two results together to give me my overall profits.

I have this code, which works, but I'm not sure the result is valid. I think it's giving me the difference overall and not showing me my "profits" for each trade.

```
const Datastore = require('nedb')
const trades = new Datastore({ filename: 'trades.json' })
trades.loadDatabase(function (err) {
    if(err) return console.error(err)
})

let sum = []
trades.find({}).exec(function (err, docs) {

    if(err) return console.log(err)

    docs.forEach(element => {
        sum.push(element.currentPrice)
    });
    let pandle = diff(sum)
    pandle = pandle.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    
    console.log(pandle)
    
})

function diff(A) {
    return A.slice(1).map(function(n, i) { return n - A[i]; });
}
```

I believe my answer lies in a foreach loop that builds an array of the `bySell` "BUY" and "SELL" pairs, and another array that keeps track of the sum of those pairs, but I'm struggling to get it working.

In the example above, I believe I should be getting: `0.3239`.

I will appreciate any help or direction!

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subtract `'BUY'` values from the sum and add `'SELL'` values.

```js
const
    fns = { BUY: v => -v, SELL: v => v },
    array = [{ buySell: "BUY", currentPrice: 431.55, _id: "GyTaUKVOCa9x5APS" }, { buySell: "SELL", currentPrice: 431.77, _id: "Re9VhGrW9ZoiOKFe" }, { buySell: "BUY", currentPrice: 431.65, _id: "TJrn63bIV8sKBFYh" }, { buySell: "SELL", currentPrice: 431.7539, _id: "qrsz2l3UVKpQEks8" }],
    profit = array.reduce((p, { buySell, currentPrice }) => p + fns[buySell](currentPrice), 0);

console.log(profit);
```